# How to Place a Border Around a ListBox Item when Pressed

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8

I have a custom style that I am using to place a border around a selected item in a ListBox. However, I have placed a ContextMenu within this ListBox which does not place a border around the selected ListBox item when then item is pressed to get the Context Menu. It seems that only when the user presses the item and then releases that the ListBox item has a border. How might I accomplish placing a border around a ListBox item for both cases, when a user wants to access the ContextMenu as well as when a user performs the normal select item action?

The Style within the Phone Application Page Resources

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property ="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="brd"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="brd" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <Image x:Name="recentImage" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="12" Width="115"/>                                
                        </Border>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="imgListContextMenu" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="edit" Click="editContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="favorite" Click="favoriteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                                <toolkit:MenuItem Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Header="delete" Click="deleteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

The ListBox within my page Grid

```
<ListBox x:Name="Recent" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" Margin="8"
                     SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MouseOver` state

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="brd">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: I placed this in the MousedOver VisualState, but it breaks the debugger without any reason.

Comment: It's because you don't have `ContentBorder` property or in simple language your Border name is `brd` while in my case it's `ContentBorder`. Anyways editing my answer.

Comment: Oh right, great catch. For some reason it still does not work though. I have also referenced http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx and tested the `FocusStates` VisualStatesGroup which has had no effect either.

Comment: I have tested this in my code and it was working. I'm developing for windows phone 8 and tested it on nokia 620 device

Comment: Hm, Yes I am testing with WP8 as well with the Nokia 920. Just to be sure, when you press and hold down on the ListBoxItem to access the ContextMenu, the border appears? For me, the border around the ListBoxItem only appears once a user selects an item and then releases their finger from the screen.

Comment: @Matthew could you please comment out that context menu code and then check. As I was using without context menu and it's color was changing when pressed.

Comment: They key lied in targeting `Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"`instead of `Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"`.

Comment: so you were playing with it's thickness rather than it's color.